# document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false); - prevents me using from using overflow: scroll; - work around?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, overflow, touchmove

Im using phonegap to build an ios app, so that you cant move the window phonegap uses `document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false);`

which is fine... but it also prevent me from using the css `overflow:scroll` on a section of text.

Is there a work arround that i can get both of these to still work ? is there a way i could load in the section of css after the js so that it overrides it ? or can i just apply the `document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false);` to the body but not its content ?

Comment: fyi window.addEventListener 'touchmove' - not document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a phonegap / cordova only work around that dosnt require you to use `document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false);` in the first place  - go into your xcode project.. porject file > supporting files > cordova.plist then at the top change 'UIWebViewBounce' to NO.

from [here](http://hankchizljaw.co.uk/tutorials/prevent-window-bounce-phonegap-1-7-ios-tip/13/05/2012/)

Comment: link broken, please fix

Answer (score 1):

To capture all the scrolling pixels you can write

```
document.addEventListener("touchStart",<method>,true/false)
document.addEventListener("touchMove",<method>,true/false)
document.addEventListener("touchEnd",<method>,true/false)
```

Have you added touchEventListener in body load function ? If you write event.preventDefault(); It will kill the event behavior that is the reason why your overflow:scroll property is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can detect the target element when "touchmove":

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {

    if (event.target.tagName != "TEXTAREA") { // Element that you don't want to be prevented default event.

          event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: do i define the element "TEXTAREA" using css hooks ? ie.     #detail-content

Answer (score 0):

In the last version cordova.plist changed by config.xml, then set

"UIWebViewBounce" value="false"